# could not convert visual basic(VB6) code to python

Tags: python, windows, vb6

I am working on a source code of a software(ELTIMA Softwares) where I got the source code in multiple language variant particularly c#, VB6, Borland C builder 6.0, Delphi 7.0, VC6, VB.NET, VC.NET

Problem is that I am not good at any of these languages, as I am a python developer. So I want this code in python. For that, I converted the VB6 code into python by using the open source utility [vb2py](http://vb2py.sourceforge.net).

But I am unable to get the proper output of the VB6. Now I am not good at VB6 however I figured out the following code to be responsible for the main software development.

```
Type=Exe
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
Form=MainForm.frm
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; mscomctl.ocx
Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; comdlg32.ocx
Form=PropertiesForm.frm
Module=Externs; Externs.bas
Object={FD79D0DD-519A-4337-B682-DC2697BCDF25}#4.0#0; HMFAx.dll
IconForm="MainForm"
Startup="MainForm"
ExeName32="VB6Example.exe"
Command32=""
Name="VB6Example"
HelpContextID="0"
CompatibleMode="0"
MajorVer=1
MinorVer=0
RevisionVer=0
AutoIncrementVer=0
ServerSupportFiles=0
VersionCompanyName="Eltima"
CompilationType=0
OptimizationType=0
FavorPentiumPro(tm)=0
CodeViewDebugInfo=0
NoAliasing=0
BoundsCheck=0
OverflowCheck=0
FlPointCheck=0
FDIVCheck=0
UnroundedFP=0
StartMode=0
Unattended=0
Retained=0
ThreadPerObject=0
MaxNumberOfThreads=1

[MS Transaction Server]
AutoRefresh=1
```

I just want here someone to please help me to make this code in python or atleast help me understand the code so that I can code this into python.

EDIT: Also please do mention if you require any other file to understand The code. I have some other files too like the "manifest file" and form files but think its for the GUI thing

Comment: i haven't done much windows development in python, but i think you'd be better off rewriting the software instead of trying a conversion. your vb6 project references some .ocx files (activex controls), which unless you are comfortable with win32 development, you can't access.

also, the above is a listing of the project settings/dependencies. it's not the application source code.

Comment: This isn't code - it is the configuration that appears at the top of the VB file.

Comment: yeah i got `comdlg32.dll` which does all the work. Its universal for other softwares. Now logic resides in some other files which at first i thought would be in the file i presented above.

Comment: I know the software does hides the folder and files in windows domain. I just wanted to understand the concept for that and the approach. If still there is some other open-source software(with source code) to do so, then please provide me the link

Comment: The only files you need are files ending in `.vb` There is no logic in this code at all - it's almost completely valid Python code anyway. You would probably benefit from taking a quick VB.NET tutorial and *then* trying to do the conversion.

Comment: Is the point that you want the code converted to be able to understand the original code, rather than that you want to run the converted code?

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I am trying to say. I want only to understand the logic from what files are provided. I got the files from http://www.eltima.com/products/hide-folder-activex/

Comment: BTW: Just checked out their site. Hiding folders is not a secure way to protect your files/IP. Same as any keygen/encryption software, it will only slow down a determined cracker.

Comment: I know that it is not a secured way. BTW,I am only looking for their code to hide the folder so that it is not visible in `"show hidden files and folders"` even if `"hide protected operating system files"` option is unchecked. I mean I want to hide the folder even in the mode the windows system files are visible.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to the answer you want, but I agree with @darkphoenix comment that you will need to rewrite the software from scratch.

However all is not lost as you will be able to see how the original code does what it does and if there are comments, should explain why it does it.

Also programming is programming - the logic is the same it's just the syntax that changes.

Comment: thats what the catch here- I could not grab the logic of the program. I want the logic from the source files, which I am trying right now

Comment: But if you have the source then surely you have the logic?

Comment: I got to know that all the files provided are only for the design pupose of the application, source file is not provided. Still, I am in hope to get some knowledge of logic from what is given in here. Hope that works. I need to get to the logic

Comment: So you don't have the source?  You have a control (either dll or ocx) and some sample source to demonstrate how to use it?

Comment: yeah I do not have the source(thats what i conclude from discussion here). Now I could ended upto now the OLE Automation concept but I think python win32 support will help me with that